# jquery - $.when() with single deferred and array of deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, deferred

I'm using jquery and have two variables.

*trackFeatures* - single ajax request, *artistRequests* - array of ajax requests

I want to do something when both trackFeatures and artistRequests have completed. For just artistRequests, I can do:

```
$.when.apply($, artistRequests).done(function() { ... }
```

Is there a way to combine the single request with the array requests? Besides adding the single request to the array or testing them sequentially.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and example :

```js
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.Deferred();
 
$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});
 
d1.resolve( "Fish" );
d2.resolve( "Pizza" );
```

Similarly if you have array of promises like `artistRequests = [d1,d2]`

You can use spread operator for array like

```js
$.when(trackFeatures , ...artistRequests ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
    console.log( v1 ); // "Fish"
    console.log( v2 ); // "Pizza"
});
```

PS: `...artistRequests` split the each value of array in single variable.

Comment: Looks like I can just use the ...artistRequests as if it was its own argument, so **$.when(trackFeatures, ...artistRequests).done(function() { ... }** is working for me, thanks!